# How to use the 7z SDK to compress and decompress a XZ file

Tags: c#, xz

How can I use 7z SDK (http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to compress/decompress a **XZ** file in C# if the input/output is a file stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I researched this problem by myself. In fact, you can't decompress XZ files using 7-Zip SDK for C#.

From http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html:

> ANSI-C compatible source code for LZMA / LZMA2 / XZ compression and decompression
>
> C# source code for LZMA compression and decompression

There is XZ and LZMA2 decoder source code only for ANSI-C. C# has only LZMA decoder. However you can still decode XZ in C# using third party binaries from [xzutils](http://tukaani.org/xz/).